# No volatile on local object variable but each thread writes to different properties - is this safe?

Tags: c#, .net, thread-safety

Given that `twoItems` is a local variable and no `volatile` keyword is used or any lock or memory barrier, is this code safe? I think it still is because one thread sets `First` property and second thread sets `Second` property but I want to make sure. If this code is not reliable and can possibly not work please advise what would be the best fix in this context.

```
private void Method()
{
    var twoItems = new TwoItems();
    Action getFirstItem = () =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        twoItems.First = new Item { SomeInt = 1, SomeString = "1" };
    };
    Action getSecondItem = () =>
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        twoItems.Second = new Item { SomeInt = 2, SomeString = "2" };
    };
    Task.WaitAll(
        Task.Factory.StartNew(getFirstItem),
        Task.Factory.StartNew(getSecondItem));
    Console.WriteLine(twoItems.First.SomeString
        + twoItems.Second.SomeString);
}

class TwoItems
{
    public Item First { get; set; }
    public Item Second { get; set; }
}

class Item
{
    public int SomeInt { get; set; }
    public string SomeString { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "thread-safe"? This definitely doesn't qualify as thread-safe in general terms. Are you asking specifically for this scenario?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov - I know I just edited the question. I mean: is this multi threading code safe? The `Method` will be invoked *from* only one thread.

Comment: @Aron - can you elaborate on this?

Comment: The code in question will not have any race conditions or locking (or lack of) issues, and will thus be "safe" to execute.

Comment: Yeah, your code doesn't change the same variable, as it uses different properties `First` and `Second` so it won't concurrent with each other and it should be thread safe

Comment: Not a problem, the .NET memory model promises that this code can work.  Under the hood that's implemented by the CLR by providing memory alignment guarantees so the processor never has to perform a bus cycle that might update memory occupied by more than one variable.  Writing threaded code would be impossible without that guarantee since a mis-aligned update could affect the state of a completely different object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code in question does not fall under the issue "thread safety" since thread safety specifically is about how multiple threads interact with the same data.

Since your code does not interact with the same data, then it doesn't exactly fall under that issue.

The shared object here is the object that has the two properties, but this does not pose any problems in this case.

As such, the code will not have race conditions or locking issues or issues with lack of locks, and will thus run as expected.

Comment: _"Since your code does not interact with the same data"_ The code shares reading of `twoItems`, so perhaps we can say that it 
"interacts".

Comment: Well, it reads the `twoItems` reference, but it does not write to any of the same areas in memory.

Comment: Sure, I do not argue with your conclusions. Just thought that wording might be slightly adjusted.